# Listening for connections in a separate thread

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

This is part of a messenger project in java. Because clients use direct connections to chat, I want eavry client to listen on some port, and others to make a socket to that address. but when i call ServerSocket.accept() in another thread it appears that all threads have been suspended. which means nothings happens after executing that command. Here is the code which makes new thread.

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while(true){
                            System.out.println("flag1");
                            Socket socket = listeningSocket.accept();
                            System.out.println("flag2");
                            new Chat(socket).setVisible(true);;
                            jTextArea1.append("successfully connected\n");
                        }
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        System.out.println("i know");
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        jTextArea1.append("error in recieving connection\n");
                    }
                }
            });
```

any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: it should be blocked most the time, bus sometimes should respond to others

Comment: @kvphxga, mre is referring to the fact that you have asked eight questions on Stack Overflow but accepted answers to only one of them. This is considered rude, unless you truly feel no one answered any of your questions adequately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when i call ServerSocket.accept() in another thread it appears that
>   all threads have been suspended

Appears how? accept() only blocks the current thread. Are you calling it in the AWT thread? e.g. an actionPerformed() method? Don't do any network operations in those methods, use separate threads.

Comment: the GUI of the program isn't loaded correctly. by the way ... this code is in the constructor.

Comment: this code is in the constructor of a JFrame. Is it in a AWT thread?

Answer (score 1):

Socket.accept() DOES block the CURRENT thread. You'll see "flag2" printed only after a connection is received. But it blocks only CURRENT thread.

I suspect you are not running the separate thread correctly (you're calling yourThreadHere.start(), not .run(), right?).

Comment: EJP is right, you are executing that code in the AWT/Swing Thread, that will freeze all your program interface. Read about the AWT/Swing threading model.

Comment: ummm ... what's that thread? this code is in the constructor of a JFrame object. Is it in the AWT/SWing thread?

Comment: Yes, java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater does not launch another thread, it executes the given runnable in the main interface thread.